# Does Confluence support Chinese language?

Tags: confluence

I am looking to know whether Confluence apps - surveys, documents, blogs etc. support Chinese characters.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Chinese is not listed in default language packs. However, you can always install the language pack in Confluence. Please take a look at this [document](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/installing-a-language-pack-214860198.html) for further details.